# What are DFSR's hardware requirements?

Tags: hardware, dfs

I'm currently looking into implementing DFSR, with the following setup:

2 Offices in the US
2 Ofices in Europe

The offices are currently using a NAS where I just copy stuff when needed, and have VPN connectivity over 20MB lines.

It will be around 1TB of files, mostly big static files, and a few little files that will be accessed/edited more often (think ms office files).

Is there a way to know what hardware would be needed to implement DFSR at my scale ? I've read about I/Os requirements, but will it be a bottleneck for me with max 40 to 60 people accessing the DFS at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general question on file server performance and is not specific to DFS. I think you'll find the File server capacity planning tool useful. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/09/16/file-server-capacity-tool-fsct-1-0-available-for-download.aspx for links.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew about that :P Will probably accept as answer if nothing else is added.